# Unable fetch collection on {strict: true} option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

When trying collection with `test.collection.col` name returns empty array:

```
db.collection('collection.col', {w: 1, strict: true}, function (err, collection) {
    if (err) { 
       console.log(err); // Collection collection.col does not exist. Currently in strict mode.
    }
});
```

But with `{strict: false}` the `collection.col` collection gets successfully.

**P.S**: I'm just noticed that this happens when collection name has name like `path.path` and doesn't happens in case `path`. So the following code works well:

```
db.collection('collection', {w: 1, strict: true}, function (err, collection) {
    if (err) { 
       console.log(err); // null
    }
});
```

Comment: 'official' json doesnt support dot notation !?

Comment: mongodb supports collection with dots like `system.indexes`, `system.js` and etc

Comment: `strict : true` means the call to `db.collection()` will return an error if the collection does not exist. That's the error your seeing. It's not related to the `.`'s in the field name. `.` characters are allowed in collection names, but not database names.

Comment: @wdberkeley I'm 100% ensure that my 'collection.col' collection exists. And I think the problem in the following line https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/db.js#L459